# Select the first element with class name inside the same parent

Tags: jquery

I have some elements with the same class name like this:

```
<h4 class="topic-header">header name</h4>
<div class="topic-text">
   some text...
</div>
<h4 class="topic-header">header name</h4>
<div class="topic-text">
    some text...
</div>
<h4 class="topic-header">header name</h4>
<div class="topic-text">
    some text
</div>
```

Now i want to select the lower upcoming div after on a header is clicked. How to do that?

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: `$(this).next()` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select the next instance of `.topic-text`

`$('h4').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next('.topic-text');
});`